# Apache Geode region vs cache

Tags: geode

When defining caches within lets say EhCache we define multiple caches like employee, departments etc. In similar fashion, do we define separate regions within  Apache Geode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [About Apache Geode](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/18/getting_started/geode_overview.html):

> Caches are an abstraction that describe a node in a Geode cluster.
>
> Within each cache, you define data regions. Data regions are analogous
>   to tables in a relational database and manage data in a distributed
>   fashion as name/value pairs.

So yes, as an analogy you can think of the *Apache Geode* `Cache` as the *EhCache* `CacheManager`, and the *Apache Geode* `Region` as the *EhCache* `Cache`.

Hope this helps. Cheers.